# Is there a way to combine two Excel files together using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, exceljs, aspose-cells

I am using ExcelJS npm oackage to generate my excel files in NestJS , it works fine for most part but I am unable to find a way to merge wroksheets from various workbooks in single new workbook ALONG with styling .
I am able to copy the cell values but that too by an expensive opeartion like this below

```
 sheetLocal.eachRow({ includeEmpty: false }, (row, rowNumber) => {
    const targetRow = book.getWorksheet(sheetLocal.name).getRow(rowNumber);
    row.eachCell({ includeEmpty: false }, (cell, cellNumber) => {
      targetRow.getCell(cellNumber).value = cell.value;
    });
    row.commit();
  });

  book.getWorksheet(sheetLocal.name).model = cloneDeep(sheetLocal.model);
});
```

So is there any easy way to combine excel files in Javascript , like for Java it can be done using Aspose library.

Comment: I guess you may try to use Aspose.Cells for Node.js via Java library (https://products.aspose.com/cells/nodejs-java/) which might suit the purpose. The code would be same as you have already used Aspose.Cells for Java.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AmjadSahi Thanks for reply. So Issue I am facing with Aspose is , I bought lifetime subscription of Aspose in 2019 for Java , now I tried to use same license for my node-js version 22.4.0 , it works but shows watermark but then I set license and it says that with that license it can only upgrade version upto 2019 and this is 2022 version that I am using. I tried to downgrade version to 19.8.0 from 22.4.0 but it didn't compile. It started showing node-gyp and python errors , which were not coming in 22.4.0 version.
So I am stuck.

Comment: Your existing license is expired to use newer versions of Aspose.Cells for Node.js via Java. But your existing license will work forever with the older versions. Moreover, to use latest version of Aspose.Cells  for Node.js via Java, you have to upgrade your subscription. As it was working with older version of Aspose.Cells for Node.js via Java, so I guess this might be configuration issue. You should check/debug and fix it on your end,  you may use the same (older) Node.js and node-java bridge which you installed previously and was working fine.